# How do you specify the outbound port for a git clone

Tags: git, ssh, port, firewall

I have a requirement that I specify the outbound port for a git clone.  In order to get through a firewall, the security folks have decreed that the port numbers on both ends of the connection be known.  I can specify the server port using the ssh url, but how do I specify the source port?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this question got downvoted, but it looks like your IT department is crazy. :-)

Unfortunately, there's no ssh option to bind the local port to a *specific* number. There is a `UsePrivilegedPort` option, which will restrict the local port to a number in the [1..1023] range. The significance of such a port is, these days, essentially nothing at all.